# Deactivate Jquery Menu Aim

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the menu aim Jquery plugin and my menu activates from `.nav > ul`. I can't seem to get the menu to deactivate and just show the initial `ul li`.

Attached is a link to my codepen version:

http://codepen.io/liondedan/pen/jEqNyO

Comment: there is no `.popover` in your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML had no `.popover` class referenced within the JS